# What is the German word for “pre-measure”?

Tags: measure-theory, translation-request, mathematical-german

I'd like to know how to translate “pre-measure” to German. Unfortunately, the wiki article on [pre-measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure) doesn't have a German version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The german word for *pre-measure* is *Prämaß*, sweet and simple, and *pre-measures* is *Prämaße*.

*Maß* simply means *measure*, and *prä* is the german version of the english *pre*.

*Maßnahme* is only then a correct translation of *measure* if *measure* is used as a synonym for *action*. So for example "Measures haven been taken" translates to "Maßnahmen wurden ergriffen", and *counter-measure* translates to *Gegenmaßnahme*.

Comment: Have you seen any instances of usage? Because if this is how it's called, something would definitely show up by googling `Premaß Maßtheorie` yet it's not the case. And googling `Premaß` alone gives PRE-Maß from statistics where PRE stands for "Proportional Reduction in Error".

Comment: @LeoSchmidt It was used extensively in the lectures on *Maßtheory* (measure theory) I attended, and it's also used by Jürgen Elstrodt in his book on measure theory called "Maß- und Integrationstheorie". Especially the latter carries a lot of weight - the book is quite widely known in the german-speaking mathematical community I believe.

Comment: I checked the book and now I see why nothing showed up in google. It's `Prämaß` not `Premaß` :-) Thank you for solving the issue.

Comment: @LeoSchmidt Uh, right, sorry. I actually *checked* with the book to make absolutely sure I wasn't mistaken before posting, and I still did not realize it says "Prä", not "Pre". Seems my german orthography skills are going south fast :-( Will fix.